# Get Domain name for non-admin user C#

Tags: c#, dns

I am trying to get domain name using below code, should I need to put any permissions on the code when this gets deployed to production ?

I tried to run this code by opening visual studio as non-admin, I did not get any errors. But just want to check before it goes to production.

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName
```

Comment: Make a test program, run it on a computer. Test it out.

Comment: I just copied the code into a console app and did the following 
`var someDomain =  System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;` it yields my current domain so should work for you unless you

Comment: Thank you @gunr2171 and DJ KRAZE. I created console app and ran the exe as non admin and I did not see any issues. Thank you for the help